# Por que no textarea com height definido o texto não fica centralizado verticalmente?

Tags: html, css, css3

Eu tenho a seguinte dúvida, se em um `input text` eu defino altura de `60px` o texto fica centralizado no campo, porem isto não ocorre no `textarea` caso eu defina um altura de `60px` também.

Procurei alguma propriedade css porém não sei se isto é possível.

```css
input, textarea{
  height: 60px;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Olá">
<textarea>Olá</textarea>
```

Comment: Mas você precisa disso pra alguma coisa ou é apenas uma dúvida ? É feio demais texto centralizado num `textarea` uahsuhas

Comment: @Gumball é dúvida mesmo, eu concordo rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentei fazer utilizando `jQuery`.

Coloquei o `<textarea>` dentro de uma `<div>`, posicionando com `absolute` e realizando o cálculo do valor `top` por `jQuery`. Também já faz o ajuste automático para quando for inserir mais palavras ou menos palavras.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

textarea {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // função que calcula e aplica a centralização
  function centralizar(){
    $('textarea').css({ 'height' : '0' }); // reseta a altura para nova contagem

    var textareaSHeight = $('textarea')[0].scrollHeight, // pega o valor do scroll do textarea
            textareaHeight = $('textarea').height(); // pega o valor da altura do textarea

    // verifica se tem scroll ou não
    if (textareaHeight < textareaSHeight) {
        var divHeight = $('div').height() / 2, // pega a metade altura da div
                top = divHeight - (textareaSHeight / 2); // calculo final do valor top

      // aplica a altura do textarea e o valor top
        $('textarea').css({ 'height' : textareaSHeight+'px', 'top' : top+'px' });
    }

  }

  centralizar(); // aplica o efeito inicial

  // ajuste automático enquanto digitar
  $('textarea').on('keydown', function(){
    centralizar();
  });

});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7j99fkbs/3/

Comment: Legal, gostei, é uma solução realmente, vou marcar como a resposta mas o que eu estava esperando era algo somente com css

Answer (score 1):

Acrescenta `vertical-align: middle` e insere uma `line-height` igual nos dois elementos, para que fiquem alinhadas verticalmente

```css
input, textarea{
  height: 60px; 
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height: 60px;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Olá">
<textarea>Olá</textarea>
```

Não consegui, fazer com que os line breaks fiquem sem a `line-height`, talvez com algum JS dê

Aqui está uma solução com JS, assim disfarça bem a meu entender:

```js
$('textarea').on('keyup', function() {
  if($('textarea').val().indexOf("\n") >= 0) { // se houver quebras de linha a line-height vai ser o default
      $('textarea').css('line-height', 'normal');
  }
  else { // se não houver quebras de linha a line-height vai ser 60px outra vez
      $('textarea').css('line-height', '60px');
  }
});
```

```css
input, textarea{
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height: 60px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="Olá">
<textarea>Olá</textarea>
```

Comment: Olá, somente com a propriedade vertical-align não muda nada..

Comment: É verade estou a tarbalhar nisso @LennonS.Bueno

Comment: Legal, estou curioso na resolução

Comment: Interessante, gostei, mas percebi que quando se quebra a linha fica um espaço muito grande, teria alguma propriedade para o texto percorrer igual o input text sem quebrar linha?

Comment: o <textarea> vai ser editável?

Comment: sim será @Ricardo

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno, coloquei uma solução com JS, não consegui fazer só com CSS

Comment: @Miguel em meu navegador continua igual, será que é o browser?

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno, experiementa este link: https://jsfiddle.net/qvbota36/

Comment: @Miguel ainda continua igual, pra você funciona?

Comment: Sim para mim está bom, estou no google chrome, e tu? @LennonS.Bueno, nesse link que te mandei funciona?

Comment: @Miguel estou no google também, aqui não funfa /:

Comment: E esse link também não dá? @LennonS.Bueno, tens de importar o jquery, como está no html